# Search and update column data based on unique row value and if new value then update as last row VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a VBA macro which will compare unique values (in column A) from Master and child sheet. Both Master and Child sheets have same columns ID (column A), Closed_count (column B), Pending_count (column C). If we find match in column "A" then will update corresponding columns "B" and "C" in master sheet.

I have written the code shown below which can search and update the matching columns but if there is new entry then I wold like that to be updated after last row in "Master" sheet. I am stuck here. Could you please help?

```
Sub Search_and_update_Data()

Dim Master, Child As Worksheet
Dim i, j, mlr, clr As Long
Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Set Child = Worksheets("Child")

mlr = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Master sheet
clr = Child.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Child sheet

For i = 2 To mlr
    For j = 2 To clr    
    'Checks column "A" with unique value from both sheets and update records in "A","B" and "C" column in Master sheet

        If Master.Cells(i, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1) Then
        Master.Cells(i, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1)
        Master.Cells(i, 2).Value = Child.Cells(j, 2)
        Master.Cells(i, 3).Value = Child.Cells(j, 3)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If values in each sheet are unique it would be faster to use Match() to find the correct row, otherwise add as a new row art the end if the sheet (ie. row `mlr + 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array of matches. when you found needed result, save in array i and j.
after checking all records, run next cycle and write all matches in master table.
And if you found the match, you shoud leave your inner cycle. The simplest way is to use goto label.

**EDIT**: i added full code with sub declaration. Tested on simle example and worked.

```
Sub Search_and_update_Data()

Dim Master, Child As Worksheet
Dim i, j, mlr, clr As Long
Dim matches()
Dim countOfMatches As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Set Child = Worksheets("Child")

mlr = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Master sheet
clr = Child.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Child sheet
ReDim matches(mlr, 2)
For i = 2 To mlr
        For j = 2 To clr
            If Master.Cells(i, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1) Then
            countOfMatches = countOfMatches + 1
            matches(countOfMatches, 1) = i
            matches(countOfMatches, 2) = j
            GoTo nextI
            End If
        Next j
nextI:
    Next i
    For i = 1 To countOfMatches
         For k = 1 To 3
            Master.Cells(matches(i, 1), k).Value = Child.Cells(matches(i, 2), k)
         Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried with this code however it gives compiler error :  
Expected Sub, Function, or Property. Could you please check